# updateTabsetPanel not working

Tags: r, shiny

Does anyone know why this simple code is not working?
What I am trying to do: make the `structure` tab active whenever users click on the run button (`input$runButton`). When I click the run button, the value of `input$runButton` gets updated, but the tab is not changed to `structure`.

Here is a simple reproducible example:

**server.R**

```
function(input, output, session) {

  #RUN button
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "allResults", 'structure')
  })

  #VAR SELECTION
  output$inputVars <- renderText({
    if (input$runButton == 0)
      return()
    print("Vars Selected")

  })

  #STRUCTURE RESULT
  output$structure <- renderText({
    if (input$runButton == 0)
      return()
    print("Structure Results")

  })


}
```

**ui.R**

```
fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Periscope Structure"),

  br(),

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(inputId="inFile", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")
    ),

    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
    numericInput("level", "Structure Level", 3, min = 2, max = 10),
    br(),
    actionButton("runButton", strong("Run!"))

  ),

  mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "allResults",
        tabPanel('Variable Selection', textOutput('inputVars')),
        tabPanel('Structure Result', textOutput('structure')))
      )
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `session` as one of the arguments to your `server` function?

Comment: Yes, I have session. Please see the reproducible code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you need to assign a `value` to `TabPanel` so you can make them active using the `updateTabsetPanel` call, so try this:

```
require(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Periscope Structure"),

  br(),

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(inputId="inFile", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")
    ),

    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
    numericInput("level", "Structure Level", 3, min = 2, max = 10),
    br(),
    actionButton("runButton", strong("Run!"))

  ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id = "allResults",
                tabPanel(value  = "inputVars",'Variable Selection', textOutput('inputVars')),
                tabPanel(value  = "structure",'Structure Result', textOutput('structure')))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #RUN button
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "allResults", 'structure')
  })

  #VAR SELECTION
  output$inputVars <- renderText({
    if (input$runButton == 0)
      return()
    print("Vars Selected")

  })

  #STRUCTURE RESULT
  output$structure <- renderText({
    if (input$runButton == 0)
      return()
    print("Structure Results")

  })


}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks so much, Pork Chop!

Comment: Going to add that this answer also works for `bs4Dash::updateControlbarMenu`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you are using shiny modules, that you have to refer to the correct session. For example, if a single tab is a module, the session of that tab won't be able to switch to another tab

To fix this, you can actually pass the session of the "parent" (container) of all your tabs into the constructor of the tab module, and then use that

Rough sketch of an example

```
shinyUI(function(request) {
    source('page/search.R', local = T)
    source('page/app.R', local = T)
    fluidPage(
        tabsetPanel(id = 'inTabset',
            tabPanel(id = 'search', 'Search', searchUI('search'), value = 'search'),
            tabPanel(id = 'app', 'App', appUI('app'), value = 'app')
        )
    )
})

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    source('page/search.R', local = T)
    source('page/app.R', local = T)
    searchSession = callModule(searchServer, 'search')
    callModule(appServer, 'app', session, searchSession)
})
```

The shiny module

```
appUI = function(id) {
    ns = NS(id)
    tagList(
        actionButton(ns('sendToHeatmap'), 'Send ortholog groups to heatmap')
    )
}
appServer = function(input, output, session, parentSession, searchSession) {
    # listen to a button press and switch to tab
    observeEvent(input$sendToSearch, {
        updateTextInput(searchSession, 'searchBox', 'funsearchterm')
        updateTabsetPanel(parentSession, 'inTabset', selected = 'search')
    })
}
```

Comment: is there a way I can pass a variable to selected instead of `selected = 'search'` something like `selected = val_sel` ? It does not respond when I use, wondering if I am not passing it as expected `appServer = function(input, output, session, parentSession,val_sel) {
    observeEvent(input$sendToSearch, {
        updateTabsetPanel(parentSession, 'inTabset', selected = val_sel)
    })
}`

Comment: I don't currently work on a shiny app anymore so I'm not sure, but I think that selected='search' is just a default and then you can still switch.